# Comparing embeddings across two different languages

Tags: similarity, keras-layer, embedding

I am using word embeddings for finding similarity between two sentences one in Greek language and one in English language. I am using keras embeddings layer for producing the embedding vectors. I was wondering if it's possible to compare these vectors.

Comment: there's many ways to compare two vectors, yes. Are "embedding vectors" a 1-d array comprised of numbers?

Comment: Thank you, yes they are embedding vectors. I am wondering if I have to use an extra vocabulary alignment to do the comparison or not.